# asp:dropdownlist doesn't save users selected value c# asp.net aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I've been trying to get this to work for hours. I think the problem is using enum but my boss insists we use it.

webapp aspx code:

```
                <label for="footerPlaceHolder_twoFactorAuthentication" class="sr-only"><asp:Localize runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorSelect %>"></asp:Localize></label>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList" CssClass="selectpicker">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorSelect %>"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorRequire %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorRecommend %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text = "<%$ Resources:UserMessages, TwoFactorNotRequired %>" ></asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:DropDownList>
                <p><asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList" CssClass="field-validation-error"  InitialValue="0" EnableClientScript="true" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></p>
```

webapp aspx.cs code:

```
var data = Utility.OAWebServiceClient.GetFullSiteData(rowToEdit);

            twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList.SelectedValue = data.TwoFactorOption.ToString();
```

webservice IOAuth2.cs code:

```
public enum WebSite2FactorOptionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    NotSelected,
    [EnumMember]
    NotRequired,
    [EnumMember]
    Recommended,
    [EnumMember]
    Required
}
```

Comment: I see no bindings, by saving you mean save the user's choice to your database right ?

Comment: @Alexandre yes, exactly

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the user selected value from DDL?

Comment: Where are you saving it?  Do you have a database with tables and a column that will accept the user's selection?

Comment: Keep in mind i'm a beginner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the values in your drop down are `int`s, but you set `SelectedValue` to string.

Try:

```
twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList.SelectedValue = ((int)data.TwoFactorOption).ToString();
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the drodown's VALUE and TEXT properties.  Your code here:

```
twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList.SelectedValue = data.TwoFactorOption.ToString();
```

Is trying to set the selected value to something like 'NotRequired'.  That won't work, because your dropdown's VALUES are 0,1,2,etc.

Something along these lines would work better:

```
twoFactorAuthenticationDropDownList.SelectedValue = ((int)data.TwoFactorOption).ToString();
```

Also, you should explicitly define the numeric values for your enum members, or else you are risking unintentional consequences if you change the order of items in your enum.

```
public enum WebSite2FactorOptionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    NotSelected = 0,
    [EnumMember]
    NotRequired = 1,
    [EnumMember]
    Recommended = 2,
    [EnumMember]
    Required = 3
}
```

Finally, since you are using the EnumMember attribute, I assume that you are serializing this enum.  Relying on the integral values of a data-contract-serialized enum can have unexpected results.